# Factoring $x^4 -8a^2x^2 -48a^4 -8bx^3 - 32a^2 bx +16b^2x^2 +64a^2b^2$

Tags: polynomials, intuition, factoring

The subject line pretty much says it all.  In my geometry class today, the following equation came up:

$$x^4 -8a^2x^2 -48a^4 -8bx^3 - 32a^2 bx +16b^2x^2 +64a^2b^2 = 0$$

Specifically, it was in the context of drawing an equilateral triangle inside a square, with one vertex in a corner of the square, and the other two vertices along two of the sides; $x$ is the distance from one vertex of the triangle to the nearest corner of the square, and $a$ and $b$ are constants.

In any case, I'm guessing the above equation is difficult to solve, so factoring, if it's possible, should make it easier.  It *is* possible, by the way, and I have the answer — I can add it, if it helps — but I have no idea how I would go about breaking the polynomial apart.

The only things I notice are the $x^4$ and $-48a^4$ terms; from what I've seen in some other posts, I gather these would be called homogeneous? Must one of the factors have a term containing only some power of $x$?  Must one have a term containing only some power of $a$, maybe with a constant attached?

So any guidance would be greatly appreciated.  And if you have any suggestions where I could learn about this kind of factoring, that would be terrific too.  (I guess by *this kind of factoring*, I mean anything beyond what's in a normal 1000-level algebra course.  I learned that stuff back in tenth grade, something like fifteen years ago, and none of the more advanced classes I've taken recently has covered anything like this.)

Comment: Even the stuff you learn in tenth generally only deals with two variables. I've never learnt factoring with x, a, **and** b.

Comment: Posting the result might help to understand more where you wanna get.

Also notice that $$(x^4 -8a^2x^2 -48a^4) +(-8bx^3  +16b^2x^2) + (-32a^2 bx+64a^2b^2)= 0$$ $$(x^2-12a^2)(x^2+4a^2)+8bx^2(-x+2b)+32a^2b(-x+2b)=0$$

Comment: Since this is a quadratic polynomial in a^2, you can solve for that. Then, try to factor the part under the square root.

Comment: The clumsy method of doing this seems to be [this].(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots)
I have simplified for some of the terms, and they seem to be manageable (as of now).

Answer (score 2):

Let us denote the proposed polynomial by $F(x,a,b)$.

(1) Note that $F(\lambda x,\lambda a,\lambda b)=\lambda^4F(x,a,b)$, So we may reduce the number of unknowns by choosing $\lambda=\frac{1}{2a}$ for example (the 2 is to reduce the coefficients by the way).

(2) So, we consider 
$$\eqalign{
F\left(y,\frac{1}{2}, c\right)&
= y^4  -8cy^3 - 8 cy +(16c^2-2)y^2 +16c^2-3\cr
&=y^4-8cy(y^2+1)+(16c^2-3)y^2 +16c^2-3+y^2\cr
&=y^2(y^2+1)-8cy(y^2+1)+(16c^2-3)(y^2 +1)\cr
&=(y^2+1)(y^2-8cy +16c^2-3)
}
$$
and you can continue from here to get:

$$F(x,a,b)=(x-2 i a) (x+2 i a) \left(x-2 \sqrt{3} a-4 b \right) \left(x+2
   \sqrt{3} a-4 b \right).$$

Comment: The question "How?" has, I realize, a couple meanings. What I mean is (and the reason I used the intuition tag and so forth) is that I'd like to learn the thought process behind solving this. Thanks.

Comment: @dmk, I edited my answer to explain to you,  How I did think about your question.

Comment: Thanks, Omran! A few questions: Even before the first step, how did you notice that this would be a good method? Was it because the exponents on $x, a, b$ for each term added up to 4? Next, why specifically $\lambda=1/2a$? That is, is it that 2 is small enough not to leave any fractions, but, when it occurs, $1/2^4$ will take out all those 16s?  And why choose $a$? For example, I tried $\lambda=1/4b$, and got $F(y,z,1/4)=y^2(y^2+1)-8z^2(y^2+1)-48z^4+4z^2-2y^3$; I couldn't make meaningful progress from there.

Comment: Finally, is there a chance that information gets lost? Specifically, we know there's an $a^4$ term to start, and so I guess we know that $y^2 + 1 = y^2 + 1^2 = \lambda^2(x^2+(2a)^2)$. However, this is looking at the answer sort of after the fact. Is there something I should be keeping in mind along the way that tells me, "Hey, this is really $1^2$"? Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: @dmk Generally it takes you several trials, the 2 is, sort of, imposes it self, the coefficients are all power of two except 48, why I chose $a$ to eliminate, it is because you polynomial starts with $x^4-8a^2x^2-48a4$. But, I didn't, a priory, *know* that this was going to work.